# TSOA Express App return cannot get endpoints

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, decorator

I am building a REST API in node.js and Typescript I am using  [**tsoa**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsoa) and swagger for documentation. The build is successful and `swagger.json` is generated successful but endpoint is not found.

> src/app.ts

```
import * as express from "express"
import * as bodyparser from "body-parser"
import { RegisterRoutes } from "./routes/routes"
import * as swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express"
import * as methodOverride from "method-override"

/** import all your routes here */
import "./routes/user"

/** End of Routes */
const app = express()

try {
  const swaggerDocument = require("../swagger.json")
  app.use("/docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument))
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Unable to read swagger.json", err)
}
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(methodOverride())
RegisterRoutes(app)

export { app }
```

> src/routes/user.ts

```
import {Get,Post,Route,Body,Query,Header,Path,SuccessResponse,Controller as Router } from "tsoa"
import { User, UserCreationRequest } from "../components/user"
import { UserController } from "../controllers/user"
@Route("users")
export class UsersRouter extends Router {
  @Get("/{id}")
  public async getUser(@Path("id") id: number): Promise<User> {
    return new UserController().getUser(id)
  }

  @SuccessResponse("201", "Created") // Custom success response
  @Post()
  public async createUser(
    @Body() requestBody: UserCreationRequest
  ): Promise<void> {
    this.setStatus(201) // set return status 201
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

When I open `/docs` It returns the swagger UI with expected endpoints but when i try to use the api like `/users/{id}` it returns 404, I am not able to understand why, Help would be appreciated.

#### Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but there is a newer and easier option in verson 2.4.5 (so you will likely need to upgrade tsoa to take advantage of it). If you add the `controllerPathGlobs` to `tsoa.json` it will find any classes that have the `@Route` decorator. So for you, you'll want the following glob:

```
{
    "routes": {
        "controllerPathGlobs": [
            "./src/routes/**/*.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

(note you'll still want to include your other config options-- I've just removed them for brevity)

Read more here: https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa#consuming-generated-routes

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using TSOA, when running from ts-node, it works fine, but after a tsc build swagger docs throws a cannot Get error.

The issue was how the swagger.json was imported, After switching from require to import, It worked!

```
import * as express from "express"
import * as bodyparser from "body-parser"
import { RegisterRoutes } from "./routes/routes"
import * as swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express"
import * as methodOverride from "method-override"

//try this 
import swaggerDocument from "../swagger.json"
/** import all your routes here */
import "./routes/user"

/** End of Routes */
const app = express()

try {
  
  app.use("/docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument))
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Unable to read swagger.json", err)
}
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(methodOverride())
RegisterRoutes(app)

export { app }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import all your router in the app starting file
see: https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa/#consuming-generated-routes

```
// controllers need to be referenced in order to get crawled by the generator
import './controllers/usersController';
```

Comment: That's right you did! I didn't look at the username when I made that comment, haha. Thanks again for your contribution to tsoa. Also, I'm glad that you're reviewing stack overflow because I don't watch it as much as I should. I'm gonna try to make a tsoa tag on here if I can figure out how to.

Comment: Sound great, always happy to help! Do you know when the new version of tsoa will be released to the npm?

Comment: I released that version and a few subsequent versions earlier this week. I’m already using your great feature. We also added strict evaluation for additional properties.

Answer (score 0):

in  my personal case it was a miss imported file. Uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your route functions, I was expecting parameters in the function but not in the url

```
@Get()
    public async getAllUsers(@Path() page: number, @Path() size: number): Promise<UserResponse[]> {
```

The correct one was:

```
@Get('/{page}/{size}')
    public async getAllUsers(@Path() page: number, @Path() size: number): Promise<UserResponse[]> {
```